# How to make a setup in visual studio along with sql server and all other required components

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, crystal-reports, installation

I am about to make a product which uses a SQL Server to store the data.

My question is how i can make the setup that includes every thing like .NET Framework, Crystal Reports, SQL Server etc. which are needed to run the application.

In short, I want to make a setup file that is independent on user's system. Setup should install all necessary component those are required to run the application.

Another question is if setup is able to install SQL Server then how can I manage the "Connection String" of my project. As I said my product must not be dependent on anything.

How can I achieve those kind of requirements? Please give me some guidelines.

Thank you.

Comment: Try wix: http://wixtoolset.org/

Comment: @zaitsman What is it ? i haven't heard about this...

Comment: wix allows you to create msi packages for free. As part of that you can specify pre-requisites (and even, license permitting, bundle them into your msi). Wix is free. If you can afford it, you can try one of the commercial products that do the same thing (e.g. InstallShield).

Comment: Thank you very much... but i am wondering about my another question that is how can i manage "Connection String" with different users ???

Comment: you can preconfigure the mssql installer with some hardcoded values (e.g. instance name etc). then when that loads up ur msi will run the script using that server name and that default instance name to create the db and assign permissions. Once that succeeds, you have everything you need for the connection string. Be wary, though, of potential collisions working with dependancies as well as limiting ur users choices in their infrastructure design.

Comment: If your using .net and mssql you are already dependent on .net and mssql...  You cannot, or should not auto install Sql Server for them. That is an enterprise product that should be configured by someone.  If you want a self contained DB, you should look at SQLite instead.

Comment: @Ryios suppose i use SQLite as a db so which will be a best management platform ??

Comment: If I knew more about what you are building, in terms of what it does, how it will be used, and where it will the software run (workstation desktop, or windows server?). I could answer that for you.  As it stands I can't say which would be best.

Comment: @Ryios i am developing a simple application that generates a bill for the customer and keep records of that bills and customer details. I thought storing data in XML might help as it does not need any configuration at client side but it is not recommended solution.  but now you are suggesting to use SQLite but i haven't used it before so i wonder where to start with SQLite.

Comment: Well typically, a client entering a bill would be on a system where the application talks to a data server.  E.g. you install Sql Server on a Windows Server etc, and the client application (where the bill is entered) talks to the data server via a web service or similar communication layer and doesn't directly make db calls (assuming desktop app) as a web app (all running on the web server) you would make db calls, but there would be nothing for clients to install, they would just go to a url in their browser and log in.

Comment: For one, requiring each desktop to install sql server, probably isn't going to happen simply because sql server costs money.  You can't destribute the same keyed copy to each client, that is why it is run on servers.  And MSSQL isn't cheap.  If you are leaning towards SQL Express you have a 10GB database size limit and might as well go SQLite at that point.

Comment: http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki

That is the SQLite .net page.  It is a database system that is sql SQL syntax, but it's self contained.  It saves on disk and runs in the same process as the calling code.  You can package it with your product and there isn't anything to install so to say, it's just a dll that goes in the bin folder.  As for managing it, you can use one of the tools http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools

Comment: @Ryios  Just in terms of 'not installing sql' - sharepoint and Symantec do that for you, so in some products that is acceptible. One needs to have a very good idea of what they are doing, though, if this becomes the 'default' option.

Comment: Sure but sharepoint and symantic don't run on the client (the desktop workstations), which is why I was asking where it will run.  If you put a requirement that a user will have to buy MS SQL Server for each desktop client, I doubt it will sell...  Also sharepoint doesn't install SQL, it just comes with a prerequisite checker that goes through the system and makes sure all required components are present.  It installs many things, but not SQL Server itself, not active directory, etc.